# How can I disable the generation of the "Summary" section in NaturalDocs?

Tags: documentation-generation

I'm experimenting with using the Natural Docs generation tool for some automated code documentation, but am finding the "Summary" section being generated inappropriate and misleading in the context I'm working in. In particular, the behaviour of using the first sentence from the various "About" categories will not work for my needs.

I'd be happy to simply suppress the section entirely, but don't know if this is possible. Does anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: There is no way to disable the "Summary" section via settings or options.

The long answer:

I wanted to achieve the same. As I found no documentation for it I take a look at the NaturalDocs source code.

There is one single line in HTMLBase.pm (search for "BuildSummary") which triggers the generation of the Summary. It should be easy to remove it or to add an option to suppress it for certain files.

The simplicity of changing or extending NaturalDocs was my reason to use it at all.